# Load the JSON data into SQL Database using R

Tags: mysql, json, r, azure-sql-database

R Code -  Trying Load the JSON File into SQLDatabase and fallen into Below Error.

```
json_file <- 'TwitterAPI/FundingData.json'
credentials <- fromJSON(json_file)
print(credentials)
#Azure SQL DataBase Connection
sqldbcnn <- odbcConnect(dsn = "AzureSQLDb", uid = "sn", pwd = "$")
twitter <- list(credentials)
twitter.df <- data.frame(twitter)
twitter.df <- select(twitter.df, data.billed_charge_local_micro, 
                 data.billed_follows, data.estimated_charge_local_micro, 
                 data.granularity, data.id, 
                 data.promoted_account_follow_rate, 
                 data.promoted_account_follows, 
                 data.promoted_tweet_timeline_engagement_rate, 
                 data.promoted_tweet_timeline_engagements)
sqlSave (sqldbcnn,
     twitter.df,
     tablename = 'Twitter_Macy_s',
     append = TRUE,
     rownames = FALSE,
     colnames = FALSE,
     verbose = TRUE,
     safer = TRUE,
     addPK = FALSE,
     fast = FALSE,
     test = FALSE,
     nastring = NULL)
close(Macy-s_DataBase_Connection)
```

While Running this code I am getting below Error:

```
"Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("billed_charge_local_micro",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"

    {
    "data": {
        "billed_charge_local_micro": [
            22000000,
            22000000,
            22000000
        ],
        "billed_engagements": [
            59,
            50,
            69
        ],
        "billed_follows": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "end_time": "2013-04-16T07:00:00Z",
        "estimated_charge_local_micro": [
            22000000,
            22000000,
            22000000
        ],
        "granularity": "DAY",
        "id": "e25e",
        "promoted_account_follow_rate": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_account_follows": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_account_impressions": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_account_profile_visits": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_clicks": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_engagement_rate": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_engagements": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_follows": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_impressions": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_replies": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_search_retweets": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_clicks": [
            65,
            75,
            81
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_engagement_rate": [
            0.0763807285546416,
            0.0857142857142857,
            0.0682392586352148
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_engagements": [
            65,
            75,
            81
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_follows": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_impressions": [
            851,
            875,
            1187
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_replies": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "promoted_tweet_timeline_retweets": [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "start_time": "2013-04-13T07:00:00Z"
    },
    "data_type": "stats",
    "request": {
        "params": {
            "account_id": "5gvk9h",
            "end_time": "2013-04-16T07:00:00Z",
            "granularity": "DAY",
            "id": "e25e",
            "start_time": "2013-04-13T07:00:00Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I do not have SQL Azure, your code works perfect in another database. Which is the error line?

Comment: This is my Error :::::::::::::;;"Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("billed_charge_local_micro",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"

Comment: Not error message. I meant which line in posted code erred out? Can you replicate your issue in another database like MS Access, SQLite, etc. using RODBC? Code ran perfect with MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert for R connections to Azure SQL, but it seems strange that you don't have something like encrypt:true in connection string:

```
sqldbcnn <- odbcConnect(dsn = "AzureSQLDb", uid = "sn", pwd = "$")
```

Take a look at this example:

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/02/ms_sql_azure.html

They are using RODBC, and they have Encrypt=yes in the connection string:

```
"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:hzgi1l8nwn.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Test_R2;Uid=your_logon_ID@hzgi1l8nwn;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Maybe you need to add similar parameter in your connection.

Comment: that doen't required. It was mapping issue and now I am able to load the Data into Database and Data Warehouse.